# Почему git reset удаляет файлы в рабочей области?

Tags: git, git-reset

Почему следующая команда git reset удаляет file1, и почему она не удаляет file2?

```
git init
echo > file1.txt
echo > file2.txt
git add file1.txt
git reset --hard
```

**результат git status перед git add:**

```
   No commits yet
      Untracked files:
          (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
                file1.txt
                file2.txt
```

Comment: Когда вы просто создаёте файлы они не отслеживаются гитом, и он ничего с ними сделать не может

Comment: маловато информации. Покажите git status перед add

Comment: @had0uken добавил git status

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4327708/6944845

Comment: @vi0 тогда да, ребята уже ответили. У вас после команды git add file1.txt - файл1 перешел в отслеживаемую зону, а файл 2 так и остался в неотлсеживаемой. git reset с параметром hard - не трогает файлы из неотлсеживаемой зоны. Чтобы удалить их воспользуйтесь git clean

Comment: @had0uken по file2 понятно. У меня нет цели удалить файл, мне нужно понять механизм работы.  Почему же file1 удален? Где есть описание этого действия?

Comment: @vi0 https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add   https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset   Также желательно почитать про "отслеживаемую" и "неотслеживаемую" зоны GIT. В любом видео курсе по GIT - на первых уроках это разбирают. Сразу станет все на свои места